# How to use guillemets with us altgr-intl layout?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, keyboard-layout

I've set up my keymap as US international with the following command:

```
$ sudo localectl set-x11-keymap us apple_laptop altgr-intl
```

which I think is equivalent to the following `setxkbmap` command:

```
$ setxkbmap us -variant altgr-intl
```

Does anyone know how to use guillemets (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemet) with this layout ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are on the two keys to the right of <kbd>P</kbd>: pressing the first with <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> produces "«", the second produces "»".

Comment: By any chance, do you know how to do english, "typographic" quotation marks (`“…”`) as well? :)

Comment: @Antoine they're on the same keys, with Shift.